# Multiple Ng-REPEAT in a page

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have the following codes on my index.html page.

```
<button id="showdogs">Dogs</button>
<div ng-repeat="list in cats">
<li>{{list.name}}</li>
</div>

<script>
$scope.cats = [
        {name:"cat1"},{name:"cat2"},{name:"cat3"}]
$scope.dogs = [
        {name:"Dog1"},{name:"Dog2"},{name:"Dog3"}]
</script?
```

I want to show

```
<div ng-repeat="dog in dogs">
<li>{{list.name}}</li>
</div>
```

when #showdogs button is pressed. 
Can anyone help me to do this using AngularJs or Jquery?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AngularJS:**

You can use `ng-show` as follows and display list:

```js
function Controller($scope) {
   $scope.displayCats = true;
   $scope.displayDogs = false;
    $scope.cats = [{name:"cat1"},{name:"cat2"},{name:"cat3"}];
  $scope.dogs = [{name:"Dog1"},{name:"Dog2"},{name:"Dog3"}];
    
    $scope.showDogs = function(){
     $scope.displayDogs = true;
      $scope.displayCats = false;
    };
    
    $scope.showCats = function(){
     $scope.displayDogs = false;
      $scope.displayCats = true;
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="Controller">
    <button id="showdogs"  ng-click="showDogs();">Dogs</button>
    <button id="showcats"  ng-click="showCats();">Cats</button>
    <div ng-show="displayCats" ng-repeat="list in cats">
    <li>{{list.name}}</li>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="displayDogs" ng-repeat="list in dogs">
    <li>{{list.name}}</li>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```js
var cats = [{name:"cat1"},{name:"cat2"},{name:"cat3"}];
var dogs = dogs = [{name:"Dog1"},{name:"Dog2"},{name:"Dog3"}];

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#showdogs").click(function(){
   $(".listDiv > ul").empty();
   $.each(dogs,function(ind){
      $(".listDiv > ul").append("<li>"+dogs[ind].name+"</li>");
    });
  });
  $("#showcats").click(function(){
   $(".listDiv > ul").empty();
   $.each(cats,function(ind){
      $(".listDiv > ul").append("<li>"+cats[ind].name+"</li>");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="showdogs">Dogs</button>
<button id="showcats">Cats</button>
<div class="listDiv">
<ul>

</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I found that angularjs method is simple. I want to display CATS List on 
 pageload. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-click` and pass the type there and in controller populate the datasource based on the type.

```
<button id="showdogs" ng-click="showItem('dog')">Dogs</button>

$scope.showItem = function(type){
   if(type === 'dog'){
      $scope.itemList = [{name:"Dog1"},{name:"Dog2"},{name:"Dog3"}];
   }
   else if(type === 'cat'){
      $scope.itemList = [{name:"cat1"},{name:"cat2"},{name:"cat3"}];
   }
};
```

In html

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemList">
   <li>{{item.name}}</li>
</div>
```

See the [**example plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/88Eq5ADKkjGsfX58Dr9J?p=preview).